Need to add more sort by option in page builder product block
I just want to add 'Most Viewed' and 'Best Seller' sort by option in the pagebuider product block. There is no such options in the Native functionality. Please provide me the solution if you guys have.

Thanks,

Create a custom module with the specified configuration, you need to add the following XML code to the di.xml file located in the Vendor/ModuleName/etc directory.
Here’s a summary of what you need to do:

Create a custom module in your Magento setup. You can name it according to your needs, but let's use Vendor/ModuleName as an example.
Add the di.xml file with the provided XML configuration code.

Here's a step-by-step breakdown:
Step 1: Create the Custom Module

Create the Directory Structure:

Navigate to the app/code directory of your Magento installation.
Create the directory structure for your custom module: Vendor/ModuleName.

The directory structure should look like this:
app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/


Create the registration.php file:
Inside Vendor/ModuleName, create a registration.php file with the following content:
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_ModuleName',
    __DIR__
);


Create the module.xml file:
In the etc directory, create a module.xml file with the following content:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_ModuleName" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>



Step 2: Add the di.xml File

Create the di.xml file:
Inside the etc directory (Vendor/ModuleName/etc), create a file named di.xml and add the following content:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="Vendor\ModuleName\PageBuilder\Model\Catalog\Sorting\CustomClassVirtual"
                 type="Magento\PageBuilder\Model\Catalog\Sorting\SimpleOption">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Custom Label</argument>
            <argument name="sortDirection" xsi:type="const">\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::SQL_DESC</argument>
            <argument name="attributeField" xsi:type="string">attribute_code</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <type name="Magento\PageBuilder\Model\Catalog\Sorting">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="sortClasses" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="custom_item" xsi:type="string">Vendor\ModuleName\PageBuilder\Model\Catalog\Sorting\CustomClassVirtual</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>



Step 3: Enable the Module

Run the following commands in your Magento root directory to enable the module and clear caches:
php bin/magento module:enable Vendor_ModuleName
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush



This setup will create a new sorting option called "Custom Label" with the attribute field attribute_code sorted in descending order. Make sure to replace Vendor/ModuleName with your actual vendor and module names if they differ.
If you have any further questions or need additional assistance, feel free to ask!
